# Basic database connection returns page not found

Tags: php, mysql, apache, apache2, lamp

I've just setup a basic LAMP server using CentOS 7 and have created 2 PHP files

**PHP file 1: index.php**

```
<?php
        echo "hello world";

        phpinfo();
?>
```

**PHP file 2: database.php**

```
<?php
        $conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'removed_actual_username', 'removed_actual_password') or die('Error connecting to mysql');
        mysql_select_db('database1') or die('Database does not exist');
        print 'All OK!';
?>
```

index.php works fine, but database.php does not work.

database.php gives me the following error:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /database.php on this server.
```

The permissions of both files are as follows:

```
[root@localhost html]# ls -al
total 8
drwxr-xr-x. 2 oshirowanen oshirowanen  41 Sep 15 10:12 .
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root     root      31 Sep 14 12:01 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 oshirowanen oshirowanen 181 Sep 15 10:11 database.php
-rw-r--r--. 1 oshirowanen oshirowanen  43 Sep 15 10:13 index.php
[root@localhost html]#
```

Any idea what I have done wrong or missed?

**UPDATE 1:**

The PHP version is 5.4.16

Comment: If you are the author of the `database.php`, please consider using updated database connector as `mysql_*` function are deprecated and subject to security and performance issues.

Comment: have you edited your phpmyadmin.conf file ?

Comment: Are running a site under a folder tree owned by `root`? That's already strange. But since `index.php` is working, I have the feeling the issue must be somewhere in your apache configuration, and not your directory structure.

Comment: Does database.php work with an echo like your other file?  Which Php version?  Could this be the fact there is no mysql module in Php 7?

Comment: @Progrock, I've just changed the database.php file to a simple hello world echo, and it works fine.

Comment: Do you have the entries for mysql listed in phpinfo's output?

Comment: @Progrock, yes, I can see many references to mysql in phpinfo.  Although, I am using MariaDB, not sure if that is the reason for the problem?

Comment: @Progrock, also, I'm using PHP 5.4.16.

Comment: Can you connect to the mysql (maria) server from the CLI?

Comment: @Progrock, yes, no problem connecting to the mysql server at all using `mysql -u [username goes here] -p`

Comment: @Progrock, and `select * from mysql.user` returns the username and localhost row being used in database.php.

Comment: Which hosts?  Try connecting via the IPv4: 127.0.0.1.  Did you restart apache (straw clutching)?

Comment: How did you install mariadb and php mysql?  Please embellish question.

Comment: Have you specified an entry in php's config for error_log?  If so can apache write to that file?  Try triggering a syntax error your echo file.

Comment: @Progrock, 127.0.0.1 gives same issue.  Apache has been restarted, still have the same issue.  mariadb was installed using the command `yum install mariadb-server mariadb`.  Also apache can write to the error_log `[Fri Sep 16 15:07:54.161661 2016] [:error] [pid 2817] [client ::1:47974] script '/var/www/html/database2.php' not found or unable to stat`.  Entry created just now.

Comment: From which repos are you installing mariadb/php from?

Comment: A bit of searching around threw up some references to selinux.  Try:  `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1`.